# State diagram and an unknown table

Tags: state-machines

[image]

I am wondering what kind of table that is, is that perhaps a state table? I am not sure what \$q_1\$ and \$q_2\$ stand for. They don't look like next state functions since these are denoted \$q^+\$ in my book.

Comment: Looks like a suggested state encoding.

Comment: You will need 2 next-state equations. One for q1+ and one for q2+ (besides an equation for your output which is specified by the "Y" term in the X/Y designations).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the state bits allocated for each state if implemented in a digital sequential state machine. In this case it is a Mealy model as the outputs, specified on the arcs depend on the current state and the current input.

Answer (score 0):

\$q_x\$ is most often the name of an output. Typically the output of gates or more complex circuit blocks.

Here the combination of the variables \$q_1\$ and \$q_2\$ and the state is bijunctive, so they are somehow equivalent to the state itself. The state seems to be altered by different input values of a circuit or gate as shown by the \$X/Y\$ notation at the branches of the diagram.